# Load specific page template based on URI

Tags: pages, templates

I have a page template that I want to load, when ever my `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is like this, `www.site.com/link/147` where the number `147` will be variable.

i.e. I would like a call a page template, whenever my `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains `/link/` in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can count on the URI always following the same pattern, e.g. `/link/###`, then you can selectively load a different template using a query variable and a rewrite (will need to flush rewrites to test):

```
/**
 * Register a query variable to check against for loading a template. 
 *
 * @param array $vars Registered query variables.
 * @return array (Maybe) filtered list of query variables.
 */
function wpdocs_add_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my-template';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpdocs_add_query_var' );

/**
 * Register an endpoint using the new query variable.
 */
function wpdocs_add_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'link/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?my-template=1', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpodcs_add_rewrite_rule' );

/**
 * Load a template based on the presence of a query variable in the request.
 *
 * @param string $template Template file.
 * @return string (Maybe) filtered template file path.
 */
function wpdocs_load_page_template( $template ) { 
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( get_query_var( 'my-template' ) ) {
            $template = get_template_directory() . '/my-template.php';
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpdocs_load_page_template' );
```

Comment: I got this error, `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wpodcs_add_rewrite_rule' not found or invalid function name in /home/cashbacktoday/public_html/st/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 503

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cashbacktoday/public_html/st/wp-includes/plugin.php:503) in /home/cashbacktoday/public_html/st/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1207`

Comment: Did you actually create the my-template.php file in your template directory first? I'm not getting any such errors. You may need to finesse the actual /link/### endpoint depending on what rewrites you already have in place are though. There could be conflicts.